# Default paper size for 4" x 6" label printer - Mac OS 10.15.7

Tags: macos, printing, system-settings

I have two 4" x 6" label printers. Every time I print a label, I have to MANUALLY select 4" x 6" output (which is often forgotten -- screwing up several labels) ANNOYING!

[image]

So I remember -- head smack -- default paper size setting in System Preferences! But go there and there is no selection for 4" x 6"

[image]

I feel like I am not the first to have this issue.

How can I set a label printer to have 4" x 6" as its default media?

Comment: Why not save it in Presets, at the top of your first dialog? Does 4x6 appear in the Paper Size drop menu in that dialog? It does for me.

Comment: That is the issue: You can see there that is does NOT show up as an option...

Comment: The list where it doesn't show is not the list I'm asking about. My printer doesn't show 4x6 in that dialog, but it does in the first dialog, next to where you have circled.

Comment: That only allows me to set the paper size once. Next time I print, it is back to 8 x 10

Comment: Even once saved as a preset?

Comment: Let me try again when I am back to that computer

Comment: It works! Answer that way and I will accept. There is also the [CUPS Method](https://help.readytoship.com.au/en/articles/1785382-how-to-set-correct-dymo-4xl-paper-size-4x6-in-mac-osx) that works too.

Comment: @drewk Hello, can you elaborate how did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to define it as a Preset, directly from the main Print dialog.

*[Example showing different settings/printer, just for locations]*

[image]

Once you set the page size in the lower marked drop menu, you can then Save Current settings as Preset, from the top drop menu.
That info should then be retained.

Comment: Hello, My main print dialog in acrobat reader is different. What is this app where it shows such dialog? How to actually fix it?

Comment: Adobe does things its own way, often ognoring the standard Apple Toolbox guidelines. I don't have Acrobat so I can't check. The picture above is the default Mac-standard print dialog available in almost all apps [except Adobe] :\

Comment: Tried Word, doesn't look like anything your screenshot shows. What app you have used for above screenshot?

Comment: Microsoft are another one that ignore the Toolbox. Just try any Apple app [or one that *does* do it properly, which is most of them.]

Comment: Thanks, Manage to see the settings, had to click Show Details on the dialog box. It does work on macOS apps and Microsoft Apps but Adobe Acrobat Reader still doesn't take these defaults.

Comment: Sorry, can't help. It's not an app I use.

Comment: no problem, you have already helped a lot :)