# How to set default paper sizes for different printers on macOS

Tags: macos, monterey, printing, system-settings

I've two printers, HP desktop A4 size and a Zebra thermal label printer for label printing 4"x6". I'm not able to set the default paper size for these printers separately and I've to manually select paper sizes whenever I switch/select a printer.

This answer comes closer to my question but not sure what the solution is or how to fix it?
[Default paper size for 4" x 6" label printer - Mac OS 10.15.7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406153/default-paper-size-for-4-x-6-label-printer-mac-os-10-15-7)

When I select HP printer it should select A4 size by default
When I select Label printer it should select 4"x 6" paper size by default.

How to do it?

P.S. My macOS is macOS Monterey